# How can an html attribute's value be captured then written as text in html?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to display class values on a webpage. I want to be able to create pages that contain many combinations of styles. Then for the sake of accuracy have the page auto display these variables. Instead of copying and pasting the string manually like this:

```
<figure class="left my-figure my-figure-50 thumbnail">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/200/" />
    <figcaption>left my-figure my-figure-50 thumbnail</figcaption>
</figure>
```

I would like to dump the classes of a parent `<figure>` in the caption area `<figcaption>` and get
[image]

I'm guessing that `.getAttribute("class")` or `.attr('class')` could be used somewhere but for my life, I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `textContent` and `className` properties of HTML elements here.

### Vanilla JavaScript Implementation:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('figure').forEach(function (figure) {
  figure.querySelector('figcaption').textContent = figure.className
})
```

```html
<figure class="left my-figure my-figure-50 thumbnail">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/200/" />
    <figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
```

### jQuery Implementation:

```js
$('figure').each(function () {
  $('figcaption', this).text(this.className)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<figure class="left my-figure my-figure-50 thumbnail">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/200/" />
    <figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Perfect! Wow I was going in the wrong direction. This even replaces the static text I had in the caption. +1